# Disabling Get-NetLocalGroup

Tags: security, winapi, powerview

I know that running NetCease tool on a host could disable other hosts from enumerating session on it.

I wonder if there is a way to disable other PowerView functions such as “Get-netlocalgroup” (namely, disable the "NetLocalGroupEnum" WIN32 API call).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is to edit the registry key "AllowRemoteRPC" (found on Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server).

See [reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/bf44232a-ca5b-4ed6-8cca-8eee3f257ed1/rpc-call-to-remote-pc-gets-access-denied?forum=winserver2008appcompatabilityandcertification).